# Call Custom function on Close button click of Dynamic Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

I have dynamic popover withing a custom plugin.

```js
(function($) {
  $(voiceIMage).popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: 'true',
    title: '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>' +
      '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="closePopover(event)">&times;</button>',
    content: 'test'
  });

  function closePopover(e) {
    console.log('Done')
  }
}(jQuery));
```

The above code is not working. How can I apply this `closePopover()` function on close button click which is dynamic popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because functions called from `onclick` attributes need to be available from the global scope. As such you need to move the definition of the `closePopover()` function to that level (ie. outside the IIFE).

*However*, a much better solution would be to use the events raised from the Bootstrap popover itself when the element is closed:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(voiceIMage).popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      html: 'true',
      title: '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>',
      content: 'test'
    }).on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
      console.log('Done')
    });

    $('.close').click(function() {
      $(voiceIMage).popover('hide');
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

For more information on the events available from the popover, see the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#events)